# Prebuilt libTooling (LLVM/Clang tools) headers and dlls for Windows with RTTI on

Tags: c++, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer, libtooling

This might not be the right place to ask this question, but I could not find an answer anywhere else.

I want to create a static-analyzer with the libTooling library, outside of the llvm source tree. On the official llvm site, I only found prebuilt binaries for the clang compiler, but nothing about the other tools.

I am aware that I can just compile myself with the RTTI=ON flag but with the low-end computer I have, it would take more than 5 hours and I also don't want a copy of the llvm source on my computer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you mean by "for Windows": MinGW or MSVC? x32 or x64?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'll be using MSVC on windows and GCC on Linux. But the question is towards the development files that are required to build my tool. On Linux you can get these built development files from the package manager, but on windows you cant.

Comment: You need different files depending on the compiler you're using, that's why I was asking. You can probably find libtooling built for MinGW in MSYS2 packages, but it's not going to work with MSVC.

Comment: You need to build your own libs, since Windows is not the main battlefield of clang.